# mongoose dropped connection after some inactivity and node js app crashes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, timeout, mlab

[image]

basically I see this when I wake up and see my monitor..

so I am pretty certain this happens after some time of inactivity..

I am using mlab as my DaaS.

```
var connection = mongoose.connect(mongoURL, (error, database) => {
if (error) return console.log(error);
console.log('[Success: connected to mlab database]');
});
```

this is my connection code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced similar issue with mlab. Try this:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var mongoConnectOpts = { 
    poolSize: 50,
    reconnectTries: 10,
    reconnectInterval: 500, 
    socketOptions: {
       keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000
    }
}
mongoose.connect(config.connectionString, { server: mongoConnectOpts, replset: mongoConnectOpts });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting a `keepAlive` might help. mLab's recommended connection settings for mongoose:

https://gist.github.com/mongolab-org/9959376